# installshield error 1628 when installing FSX on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, flight-simulator-x

I have just successfully uninstalled FSX from an ageing XP machine and am trying to install it on a computer running Windows 8.1. However the installer gets part way through opening, it then crashes giving me a 1628 error. I have tried renaming and deleting the installshield folder in the common files folder, I still get the error. Any thoughts on what the problem might be? Please do not give me a link to the Microsoft support page on 1628 errors because it is completely useless for anyone running windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after hours of trying to get it to install I now have FSX running stable, if you are having the same problem I had here is what I did to get it to install.

Step 1: Got to the settings app in windows 8.1 and create a new account

Step 2: Log onto the new account and insert the first disk for FSX open the disk in the windows file manager and find the installer application

Step 3: right click on the application and run as an administrator

Step 4: FSX should now start to install, follow the on-screen instructions , it took around an hour for my install to complete but it may take longer on other computers

I hope this helps those having similar problems

if it still does not install make sure any installwizard folders are deleted from the common files folder in program files and that no installwizard processes are running. Once you have done this try the installation again.

If you need further information please leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

I went to Control Panel Programs, run programs made for older versions of Windows, let it look at the setup.exe on the install disc.  It recommended XP SP3 and I clicked on Test.  The whole installation went like clockwork, prompting for disc after disc, and it now runs flawlessly (although not using super-wide screen on my new machine)
Enjoy!

Comment: Yes that would work for first time installations but in my case a version of FSX had been previously installed, and there was some kind of registry error because of that as well as an update from Windows 8 to 8.1.  That was causing the error not the fact that FSX only works on newer versions of windows with compatibility settings. A clean install of FSX should work without a problem on windows 8.

Answer (score -5):

To resolve error 1607 and 1628, follow the guide:
http://simus-paradise.forumactif.com/t1017-erreur-1607-et-1628#36973
It works fine.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/173484)

Comment: ok, I'll try to resume. First open regedit.exe and found "F535B2CF-C9BB-4162-B03A-02D69". You must delete every key simalar, possible 3 or 4, all in HKEy local machine. Second: Go to programFiles + CommonFiles + InstallShield + Driver + 11 + Intel32. Inside Intel32, right clic on the 3 IDriver and in Compatibility, check "use as administrator". Do for the 3 IDriver. That's All.